# Can I use the memory profiler dev tool on a Flutter app in release mode?

Tags: android, flutter, memory-profiling

I want to understand my flutter apps (testing on Android) memory usage while in release mode (to get an accurate understanding of release performance).

When I run 'flutter run --release' no observatory url is given like when run in debug...

This is what is shown in debug mode but not in release...

```
An Observatory debugger and profiler on GH J047X is available at: http://127.0.0.1:46841/6uuUuFP4yEU=/
```

Answer (score 1):

To test your app with devtools
You should run it in profile mode:

```
flutter run --profile
```

With the command line

this will run your app in profile mode
it's actually same as release mode but with extra code that let you profile it with the dev tools

once you run it and the app is installed on your emulator, you can see the keyboards shortcuts for the actions you can execute like taking screenshots, opening devtools...